# Проблемы с передачей JSON данных по Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, smarty

Если сразу к делу, то JS:

```
text = $("#loadmore").val();
jsonRequest = JSON.stringify({"requestData": text});
console.log(jsonRequest); //возвращает {"requestData":"abc"}

$.ajax({
  url: '/index.php',
  type: 'POST',

  data: jsonRequest,
  contentType: "application/json",

  cache: false,

  success: function(data, xhr)
  {

    console.log(JSON.parse(data));

  }
```

Кодирую данные в JSON и передаю их на сервер по POST. На сервере принимаю следующим образом, использую Smarty:

```
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    //$request = json_decode($_POST);
    //$se->assign("test", $request); <- попытки работать с реальными данными
    $se->assign("output", 'text'); //<- пробую просто передать статические JSON данные
}

if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    $ajax_request = true;
}

$se->display($ajax_request ? 'output.tpl' : 'example.tpl');
```

Так как проверка на AJAX-запрос прошла запускается output.tpl:

```
{$output|@json_encode}
```

Результатом выходит:

```
console.log(JSON.parse(data)); //null
```

Обычные текстовые данные я уже передавал на сервер, все работало. Я где-то накосячил с заголовками, явно, где-то не кодируются JSON данные и все плывет... Но за 2 часа поисков я не понял тольком ничего, может кто-то подскажет?

Спасибо за внимание.

Comment: мб данные не в $_POST передаются, а непосредственно в теле запроса, попробуйте file_get_contents("php://input")

Comment: @Jbyh Воу, это и есть проблема. Перепроверил все передается теперь. Но так и должно быть? Почему данные не передаются в POST? И как это исправить это ж явно не должно так работать?

Comment: Уберите `JSON.stringify` и ловите `$_POST['requestData']`.

Comment: @Visman тогда и `contentType: "application/json",` убрать тоже? И тогда я передаю вновь обычный текст. Я так понимаю JSON передается своими способами?

Comment: Значит принимайте данные через file_get_contents("php://input") как Jbyh написал. Через $_POST идут только данные отправленные Content-Type = application/x-www-form-urlencoded или multipart/form-data

Comment: @Visman Окей, в этом и был вопрос. Большое спасибо!