# Ajax передает undefined через POST

Tags: php, jquery, json

Ajax передает undefined через POST, хотя переменные определены.

JS:

```html
function addProduct() {

var itemName  = $('#newItemName').val;
var itemPrice = $('#newItemPrice').val;
var itemCatId = $('#newItemCatId').val;
var itemDesc  = $('#newItemDesc').val;

var postData = {itemName: itemName, itemPrice: itemPrice,
                itemCatId: itemCatId, itemDesc: itemDesc};

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    async: false,
    url: "/admin/addproduct/",
    data: postData,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        alert (data['message']);
        if (data['success']){
            $('#newItemName').val('');
            $('#newItemPrice').val('');
            $('#newItemCatId').val('0');
            $('#newItemDesc').val('');
        }
    }
});
}
```

И экшен который должен получить данные от этой функции:

```html
function addproductAction(){
$itemName   = $_POST['itemName'];
$itemPrice  = $_POST['itemPrice'];
$itemDesc   = $_POST['itemDesc'];
$itemCat    = $_POST['itemCatId'];

$res = insertProduct($itemName, $itemPrice, $itemDesc, $itemCat);

if($res){
    $resData['success'] = 1;
    $resData['message'] = 'Изменения успешно внесены';
} else {
    $resData['success'] = 0;
    $resData['message'] = 'Ошибка изменения данных';
}
echo json_encode($resData);
return;
}
```

Вот откуда должны передаться переменные:

```html
<table>
<tr>
            <td>
                <input type="edit" id="newItemName" value=""/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="edit" id="newItemPrice" value=""/>
            </td>
        <td>
            <select id="newItemCatId">
                <option value="0">Главная категория</option>
            {foreach $rsCategories as $itemCat}
                <option value="{$itemCat['id']}">{$itemCat['name']}</option>
            {/foreach}
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <textarea id="newItemDesc"></textarea>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" value="Сохранить" onclick="addProduct();"/>
        </td>

    </tr>
</table>
```

При проверке переменных `$itemName` другие переменные оказываются не определены.
Может ajax написан не правильно? Потому что в базу заносятся `undefined` значения.

Comment: надо не `$('#newItemName').val;`, а `$('#newItemName').val();` видимо....... ну и ниже тоже

Comment: БлагодарЮ!!!!!!!!
Очень долго искал в чем ошибка

Comment: Ща я предложу закрыть твой вопрос неожиданным дубликатом (хотя такие вопросы обычно закрываются с причиной "Вопрос вызван проблемой, которая больше не воспроизводится, или опечаткой")

Comment: Еще раз спасибо, сейчас почитаю как находить ошибки))

Comment: ну и раз у тебя PHP еще фигурирует, то до кучи тогда [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в PHP коде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/701142/191482) | https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/701817/191482

Comment: xdebug есть )) Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Что если попробовать словить данные в

> file_get_contents("php://input")

[Проблемы с передачей JSON данных по Ajax](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/700147/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b9-json-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%bf%d0%be-ajax#comment1038804_700147)

Или передавайте не JSON'ом, а обычным текстом:

> Уберите JSON.stringify и ловите $_POST['requestData']

[Проблемы с передачей JSON данных по Ajax](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/700147/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b9-json-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%bf%d0%be-ajax#comment1038820_700147)